# Rails where.not, include record having nil attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've a `Order` model having a attribute `skip_reason`. I want to list out all the order that has `skip_reason` other than `full` and `locked`.
I'm using `where.not` but it do not return the orders having `nil` on the `skip_reason` column.

I came up with the following condition,

```
> orders.pluck(:skip_reason)
=> ["locked", nil, nil, "unavailable", nil, nil, "locked", nil, nil, "full"]

> orders.where.not(skip_reason: ["full", "locked"]).pluck(:skip_reason)
=> ["unavailable"]
```

So how can I list those orders that has `nil` value for `skip_reason` column? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the SQL output from the above query?

Comment: Since you are using rails 4 as @Ursus pointed out you will have to use raw SQL as `orders.where("orders.skip_reason IS NULL OR orders.skip_reason NOT IN ('full','locked')")`. Rails 5 does offer an `or` and it would look something like `orders.where.not(skip_reason: ["full", "locked"]).or(orders.where(skip_reason: nil))`

Answer (score 2):

Tried this in rails 4 and it seems to work. Is that okay for you? Otherwise I think you should go with raw SQL for the where clause

```
orders.where(skip_reason: [nil, "unavailable"])
```

Comment: Thanks,  but I may have other data in those cases.